# Is there a way I can pull unique links into a Data Studio report?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm self thought in data studio and am currently creating a database of all my companies customers. As a part of this database, I want our sales team to have access to all of the customers past and current information. This includes a unique link to a companies profile. We work off Google Sheets so I have a google sheets document with the customers information including the unique link. This would currently be fore 1,700 customers so I can't do them manually!

I want to make a nice button that would say "Customer profile" which would be created from this unique hyperlink. The only way I can figure out doing this is by using a one cell table and having the long hyperlink displayed. Is there a way I can use an image to create a unique button when the database is filtered? I.E if I filter the database to show company X's information a button will have their profile pulled from the sheet.

Additionally (a lesser question because it's more for ease instead of functionality), there is a form that our sales team can fill out during the call which I currently have embedded. Is there a way to embed a JotForm form through google sheets also? It means we would be able to pre-populate the form and the sales-person wouldn't have to waste time filling out a customer reference or company name etc.

Any help would be really appreciated! Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only an answer to your first question.

You can create a Calculated Field in your data source.

Here:
[image]

Let's say that you have "Company_Name" and "Website_URL" fields in your data source. Calculated Field will look like this:

HYPERLINK(Website_URL,Company_Name)

Then you name this field for example "Company_Website_Link" and add this to your work.